# UTC Date To Current TimeZone String and Result StringDate to Current TimeZone Date

Tags: ios, iphone, date, swift3, nsdateformatter

I get the current date in UTC and I converted it into Local TimeZone that result comes in string.

Now, I converted that Result String Date into a Date with the same Local TimeZone but it gives the date in UTC.

Below is the Code I am using:

```
    print("current date :\( Date())") //current date : 2017-03-08 11:11:12 +0000

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
    let localDate : String = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

    print("localDate date :\(localDate)") // localDate date: 08-03-2017 16:41:12 +0530

    let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
    let dateCurrent = dateFormatter1.date(from: localDate)!

    print("dateCurrent date :\(dateCurrent)") // dateCurrent date: 2017-03-08 11:11:12 +0000
```

**dateCurrent**

I want in

```
08-03-2017 16:41:12 +0530
```

only of type Date not of type String.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Could you please add more clarity on what you are wanting to do with this date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your Answers,

I dug out and I found the solution. Here I am sharing the code.

```
    let currentDate = Date()

    let CurrentTimeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
    let SystemTimeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.current

    let currentGMTOffset: Int = CurrentTimeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: currentDate)
    let SystemGMTOffset: Int = SystemTimeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: currentDate)

    let interval: TimeInterval = Double(SystemGMTOffset) - Double(currentGMTOffset)

    let todayDate: Date = Date(timeInterval: interval, since: currentDate)

    print("  Today Date : \(todayDate)")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, Hope it helps

```
let date: String =  "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
    var dateArr = date.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let dateCurrent  = (dateArr [0] )
    print(dateCurrent)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how `Date` objects work. You simply keep the date object until you need to output it to the user or an API, at which point you can convert it to a string in the appropriate time zone.

A `Date` object essentially just wraps a unix timestamp with some helper methods for dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your **dateFormatter**. Here is my code to conver UTC to Local and Local to UTC:

```
    convertUTCtoLocal(strUTCDate: "09-03-2017 03:54:00")
    convertLocalToUTC(strUTCDate: "09-03-2017 09:24:00")
```

**Convert UTC to Local**

```
    func  convertUTCtoLocal(strUTCDate: String){
    let dateFormater : DateFormatter = DateFormatter();
    dateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

    let dateFromString = dateFormater.date(from: strUTCDate)

    dateFormater.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local as TimeZone!
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

    let localData = dateFormater.string(from: dateFromString!)
    print("Your local date is \(localData)")        
}
```

**Convert Local to UTC**

```
   func  convertLocalToUTC(strUTCDate: String){
    let dateFormater : DateFormatter = DateFormatter();
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormater.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local as TimeZone!

    let dateFromString = dateFormater.date(from: strUTCDate)

    dateFormater.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") as TimeZone!;
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

    let localData = dateFormater.string(from: dateFromString!)
    print("Your UTC date is \(localData)")        
}
```

Comment: I want Date type not date in String type. Thanks for your answers. I mentioned that in my question :)